# Scroll to element compatible with all browsers

Tags: javascript, scroll

Hi im trying to make it scroll to the element on click. It works fine with scrollToView, but its not compatible with all browsers.

Is there an alternative that does the same functionality but is compatible with older IE?

Comment: `scrollToView pollyfill` is what I would search

Comment: https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can see this https://caniuse.com/scrollintoview

> The `Element.scrollIntoView()` method scrolls the current element into the visible area of the browser window. Parameters can be provided to set the position inside the visible area as well as whether scrolling should be instant or smooth.

[image]